# display: none still inheriting

Tags: javascript, html, css, .net, dom

A dynamically created form is rendering strangely **even with the style sheet disabled**.

the form shows and hides a wide range of details based on which options are selected.

so, for example, a number of the following will have been rendered with C#.net ...

```
formOutput += "<div class=\"field textBox\" id=\"" + field.Id + "\"><div class=\"labelTB\"><label for=\"" + field.Id + "\" class=\"" + reqClass + "\">" + field.Name + requirement + "</label></div>" +
        "<input type=\"text\" class=\"numInput\" id=\"" + field.Id + "_tb\" name=\"" + field.Name + "\" onkeyup=\"Service.refresh(this); numCheck(this)\" onclick=\"numCheck(this)\" />" +
        // numButtons:
        "<div class=\"minus plusMinus\" id=\"minus_" + field.Id + "\" onmousedown=\"numBox(this)\" /></div>" +
        "<div class=\"plus plusMinus\" id=\"plus_" + field.Id + "\" onmousedown=\"numBox(this)\" /></div></div><br />";
```

...and then the parent node is hidden onload by JS:

```
var setVisibility = function (id, bool) {
  try {
        get(id).style.display = (bool) ? "block" : "none";  
   } catch (e) {
     return false;
   }   
  return bool;
}
```

However, when there are a large number of hidden fields, I am getting a considerable space in the middle of my form.

I have tried all sorts of solutions with little success. simply moving everything up is not easily viable (the form is much much more complicated than I can show here)...

i have even tried the following:

```
var setVisibility = function (id, bool) {
  try {
    get(id).style.display = (bool) ? "block" : "none";
    get(id).style.position = (bool) ? "relative" : "absolute";
    get(id).style.height = (bool) ? "auto" : "0px";
    var children = get("containerType").childNodes
    for (var i in children) {
      if (children[i].style) {
        children[i].style.display = (bool) ? "block" : "none";
        children[i].style.position = (bool) ? "relative" : "absolute";
        children[i].style.height = (bool) ? "auto" : "0px";
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return bool;
}
```

what is causing this problem? is there a solution?

(see image below)

[image: DOM space]

Comment: +1 for using paint ;)

Comment: can you post URL or jsfiddle of actual code showing issue

Comment: Have you tried hard coding some styles via CSS directly. If this then works it shows that your .net logic is at fault. Alternatively it'll help you build up the correct CSS to bring about the desired visual result.

Comment: see answer below. there's a rogue <br /> in there.  I tried many other solutions with little success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a br-tag at the end of you code (after the div with id=plus_??) which will always display, regardless of whether you hide the divs or not. You could but the br-tag inside one of the divs to achieve what you want

```c#
formOutput += "<div class=\"field textBox\" id=\"" + field.Id + "\"><div class=\"labelTB\"><label for=\"" + field.Id + "\" class=\"" + reqClass + "\">" + field.Name + requirement + "</label></div>" +
        "<input type=\"text\" class=\"numInput\" id=\"" + field.Id + "_tb\" name=\"" + field.Name + "\" onkeyup=\"Service.refresh(this); numCheck(this)\" onclick=\"numCheck(this)\" />" +
        // numButtons:
        "<div class=\"minus plusMinus\" id=\"minus_" + field.Id + "\" onmousedown=\"numBox(this)\" /></div>" +
        "<div class=\"plus plusMinus\" id=\"plus_" + field.Id + "\" onmousedown=\"numBox(this)\" /></div><br /></div>";
```

...or you could just provide the br-tag with a class or id and use that to show and hide along with the divs

Comment: many thanks, well spotted, this was the correct answer. Amazing how obvious something can be to a fresh set of eyes! i buried a <p></p> in the div instead and it's just fine now.